# Why two error signs is visible when EditText validate?

Tags: android, validation, saripaar

For validation I have used saripaar validation library. When form is not valid it gives a red error sign with a message but when I click on error field another red error sign also appeared this extra red sign is unexpected. How can I remove this extra error sign?

Screenshot :

[image]

Source code :

```
package com.brainstation.ib.abbl.ui.activities;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.StyleSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.ValidationStyle;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.R;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.common.activities.TopMenuActivity;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.common.constant.MessageText;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.common.constant.PreferencesKey;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.common.enums.ResponseCode;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.common.model.BaseResponse;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.common.util.CustomLoadingDialog;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.model.activitylog.loglist.ActivityLogModel;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.model.authentication.ChangeLogInMessageModel;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.model.authentication.LoginPasswordChangeRequest;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.network.provider.ApiProvider;
import com.brainstation.ib.abbl.ui.adapter.NotificationListAdapter;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.ValidationError;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.ConfirmPassword;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.NotEmpty;
import com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.annotation.Password;
import com.pixplicity.easyprefs.library.Prefs;
import com.weiwangcn.betterspinner.library.BetterSpinner;

import java.util.List;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.OnClick;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class ChangeLoginPasswordActivity extends TopMenuActivity {

//AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation = new AwesomeValidation(ValidationStyle.BASIC);

@BindView(R.id.etCurrentPassword)
@NotEmpty
TextInputEditText etCurrentPassword;

@BindView(R.id.txtChangeLogInMessage)
TextView txtChangeLogInMessage;

@BindView(R.id.txtChangePassTitle)
TextView txtChangePassTitle;

@BindView(R.id.rootLinearLayout)
LinearLayout rootLinearLayout;

@BindView(R.id.textInputLayout1)
TextInputLayout textInputLayout1;

@BindView(R.id.textInputLayout2)
TextInputLayout textInputLayout2;

@BindView(R.id.textInputLayout3)
TextInputLayout textInputLayout3;

@BindView(R.id.etNewPassword)
@Password
TextInputEditText etNewPassword;

@BindView(R.id.etConfirmPassword)
@ConfirmPassword
TextInputEditText etConfirmPassword;

@BindView(R.id.top_menu)
LinearLayout topMenu;

private CustomLoadingDialog dialog;

private Validator validator;
private String authToken;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_login_password);

    //awesomeValidation.addValidation(ChangeLoginPasswordActivity.this, R.id.etCurrentPassword, "[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+", R.string.emptyError);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    setTopMenu();

    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("force") != null)
        topMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else {
        topMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    dialog = new CustomLoadingDialog(this);
    authToken = Prefs.getString(PreferencesKey.AUTH_TOKEN, null);
    callMessageApi();

    validator = new Validator(this);
    validator.setValidationListener(new Validator.ValidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValidationSucceeded() {
            callApi();
        }

        @Override
        public void onValidationFailed(List<ValidationError> errors) {
            for (ValidationError error : errors) {
                View view = error.getView();
                String message = error.getCollatedErrorMessage(ChangeLoginPasswordActivity.this);
                if (view instanceof AppCompatEditText) {
                    ((AppCompatEditText) view).setError(message);
                }
                if (view instanceof TextInputEditText) {
                    ((TextInputEditText) view).setError(message);
                } else if (view instanceof BetterSpinner) {
                    ((BetterSpinner) view).setError(message);
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
private void callApi() {
    dialog.show();
    LoginPasswordChangeRequest request = new LoginPasswordChangeRequest();
    request.setOldPassword(etCurrentPassword.getText().toString());
    request.setNewPassword(etNewPassword.getText().toString());
    request.setUserName(Prefs.getString(PreferencesKey.USER_ID, ""));
    request.setIpAddress("");
    Call<BaseResponse> call = ApiProvider.getApiClient().changeLoginPassword(authToken, request);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<BaseResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<BaseResponse> call, Response<BaseResponse> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                if (response.body().getResponseCode() == ResponseCode.OPERATION_SUCCESSFUL.getCode()) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, "Password changed successfully", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                            .setAction("Done", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View view) {
                                    Prefs.clear();
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LogInActivity.class);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            }).show();
                } else if (response.body().getResponseCode() == ResponseCode.AUTHENTICATION_FAILED.getCode()) {
                    if (getIntent().getStringExtra("force") != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Mismatch Information.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), MessageText.TOKEN_EXPIRED_MSG, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        gotoLogin();
                        finish();
                    }

                } else if (response.body().getResponseCode() == ResponseCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT.getCode()) {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, response.body().getErrors().get(0), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, MessageText.ERROR_MSG, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } else {
                Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, MessageText.ERROR_MSG, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            dialog.cancel();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<BaseResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            dialog.cancel();
            Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, MessageText.ERROR_MSG, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@OnClick(R.id.backBtn)
public void back(View view) {
    checkAuthAndGotoActivity(ChangeLoginPasswordActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
}

@OnClick(R.id.submitButton)
public void submit(View view) {
    validator.validate();
}

public void callMessageApi() {
    dialog.show();
    ApiProvider.getApiClient().getMessageChangeLogin(authToken).enqueue(new Callback<ChangeLogInMessageModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ChangeLogInMessageModel> call, Response<ChangeLogInMessageModel> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                message = response.body().getItems();
                showMessage();
                dialog.cancel();
            } else {
                dialog.cancel();
                Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, response.body().getErrors().get(0).toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ChangeLogInMessageModel> call, Throwable t) {
            Snackbar.make(rootLinearLayout, MessageText.ERROR_MSG, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

public void showMessage() {

    if (message == null) {

    } else {
        String steps = "Note: " + message;
        String title = "Change Password";

        SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString(title);
        ss1.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.BOLD), 0, ss1.length(), 0);
        txtChangePassTitle.append(ss1);
        txtChangePassTitle.append("\n");
        txtChangePassTitle.append(steps);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    checkAuthAndGotoActivity(ChangeLoginPasswordActivity.this, ServicesActivity.class);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_to_right, R.anim.right_to_left);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**view instanceof AppCompatEditText** and **view instanceof TextInputEditText** both return **true**. So, it's set two error icon.

You can change your conditions in onValidationFailed() method as bellow to avoid this scenario.

```
if (view.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("AppCompatEditText")) {
            ((AppCompatEditText) view).setError(message);
} else if (view.getClass().getSimpleName().equalsIgnoreCase("TextInputEditText")) {
            TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) view.getParent().getParent();
            textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
            textInputLayout.setError(message);
}
```

Comment: Nice explanation...Long time ago I placed this question and solved also..Thanks :)